# Select rows around a marker R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, apply

I'm trying to select 100 rows before and after a marker in a relatively large dataframe. The markers are sparse and for some reason I haven't been able to figure it out or find a solution - this doesn't seem like it should be that hard, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Here's a very small simple example of what the data looks like:

```
timestamp talking_yn transition_yn
0.01      n          n
0.02      n          n
0.03      n          n
0.04      n          n
0.05      n          n
0.06      n          n
0.07      n          n
0.08      n          n
0.09      n          n
0.10      n          n
0.11      y          y
0.12      y          n
0.13      y          n
0.14      y          n
0.15      y          n
0.16      y          n
0.17      y          n
0.18      y          n
```

I've tried using different methods from a variety of answers (`lag` from `zoo` or `dplyr`), but they all focus on selecting one row or subsetting only those rows with the marker. For the dummy example data, how would I select the 5 rows before and after the `transition == 'y'` row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a quick function for that:

```r
#' Lead/Lag a logical
#'
#' @param lgl logical vector
#' @param bef integer, number of elements to lead by
#' @param aft integer, number of elements to lag by
#' @return logical, same length as 'lgl'
#' @export
leadlag <- function(lgl, bef = 1, aft = 1) {
  n <- length(lgl)
  bef <- min(n, max(0, bef))
  aft <- min(n, max(0, aft))
  befx <- if (bef > 0) sapply(seq_len(bef), function(b) c(tail(lgl, n = -b), rep(FALSE, b)))
  aftx <- if (aft > 0) sapply(seq_len(aft), function(a) c(rep(FALSE, a), head(lgl, n = -a)))
  rowSums(cbind(befx, lgl, aftx), na.rm = TRUE) > 0
}

dat[leadlag(dat$transition_yn == 'y', 2, 4),]
#    timestamp talking_yn transition_yn
# 9       0.09          n             n
# 10      0.10          n             n
# 11      0.11          y             y
# 12      0.12          y             n
# 13      0.13          y             n
# 14      0.14          y             n
# 15      0.15          y             n
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE, text="
timestamp talking_yn transition_yn
0.01      n          n
0.02      n          n
0.03      n          n
0.04      n          n
0.05      n          n
0.06      n          n
0.07      n          n
0.08      n          n
0.09      n          n
0.10      n          n
0.11      y          y
0.12      y          n
0.13      y          n
0.14      y          n
0.15      y          n
0.16      y          n
0.17      y          n
0.18      y          n")
```

Comment: (This simple function fails when `length(lgl) < 2`. I might fix it at some point ...)

Comment: Oh, good to know. I also noticed that it fails if only looking at before or after (so `dat[leadlag(dat$transition_yn == 'y', 2, 0),]` not important for my purposes and can just take out the the bef or aft components of the function to get them isolated - but if you're really interested in fully functionality it might be worth exploring. Thank you for this - super handy!

Comment: Mik, fixed, see the edits (minor).

Comment: Very cool, thanks!